# Meaning of "remain" ("remain concerned")

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What does "remain" imply in sentences like this: "The Government of X remains deeply concerned about the human rights situation in the country"?

a) The Government has been concerned for a while and continues to be so.
b) The Government examined the human rights situation and, as a result of their examination, is now concerned.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with your first guess (a).

To **remain deeply concerned** means that the government's apprehension regarding human rights issues within its own borders has not dissipated or even diminished.

In other words, prior to this point in time, concern has been demonstrated and, as of now, that situation is unchanged; the aforementioned concern persists.